# 'Extract' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

`Extract` function is not available in SQL Server 2014? I want to extract year and month form a date or any other. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'Extract' function used in oracle. you can use 'DATEPART' or 'YEAR' or 'Month' or 'Day' for extract date details on sql server. try the following T-sql

```
DECLARE @currentDate DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, @currentDate);
SELECT DATEPART(mm, @currentDate);
SELECT DATEPART(dd, @currentDate);

SELECT YEAR(@currentDate);
SELECT MONTH(@currentDate);
SELECT DAY(@currentDate);
```